# How to get access for print from IIS hosting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, crystal-reports

When I run my application from Visual Studio print is working, but when I host it in IIS print is not working(Crystal Report)

Comment: "is not working" is ***not*** a valid error description. please provide us more information - _any_ information - that could be useful in troubleshooting your problem. for example: code, expected behavior, actual behavior, error messages. but without you providing us those details, _how_ do you think it possible for anyone to be able to help you? please also read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Give IIS user access to use installed printers on the computer. When you print from IIS , you're logged in as a system default user who by default doesn't have proper printer access setup in the registry.You need to give printer access to the default system user by adding few entries in the registry.

Comment: I gave printer access to the application pool I'm using still the printing part skips

Comment: Go to IIS, First find the Application Pool your app is using and then go to Application Pool details and find the Identity it is using. Change this Identity to your/some other account that has printer access.